# Google Script for Spreadsheet to Hide Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, integration, jotform

We currently use JotForm to collect submissions, and have those submissions collect in a [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JMowwhCQoOMX1RZdcHCXTxUbHtN-iJ4MuFvYUY0KWUA/edit?usp=sharing). We need to "mask" two column's entries (NOT the header), which we typically default to `****`. Our current code masks one column (Column B) but we would like to mask another (Column R).

Does anyone know where I would inject a piece that would include masking Column R in addition to Column B? ("B2:B" masks Column B.)

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pins = ss.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  for (var row = 2; row < pins.filter(String).length + 2; row++){
    ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(row,2).setValue("****")
  }
}
```

Form URL: https://form.jotform.com/81144822339153

Comment: And? What's your question? What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to know how to add in a line or whatever to hide Column R. I did not create the code above - a colleague who's no longer at the company did. So however I can streamline the code to mask both Column B and R, I am asking for assistance.

Comment: Some very basic research (Script Editor -> Help) on what the existing code is doing would be a great way to start. Alternately, using your preferred search engine with terms like `"apps script spreadsheetapp"` or `"app script getRange"`  would help you immensely.

Comment: I know what the existing code does. I don't know where I inject the Column R part in because where I've tried didn't work; it only worked on Column B. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Your current question does not show any indication of how you've tried to modify the script (or else I would not have asked). Further, your question indicates that you believe `"B2:B" masks Column B` - this is incorrect. "B2:B" is an A1 notation string that indicates what `Range` object should be acquired from the active worksheet, and the values in this range are stored in the `pins` variable. The rest of your script treats `pins` as read-only.